# Unable to get Django HttpResponse

Tags: python, html, django

A little description of what i m trying to do.
I want to make a User Interface (web/HTML) through which i can send the commands to router and display the result on the Webpage/HTML.

Here's the code i m using:-

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from first_app.forms import CmdForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
  my_dict = {'insert_me': ""}
  return render(request,'first_app/index.html',context=my_dict)

def form_name_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = CmdForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
        from netmiko import ConnectHandler
        devices = {
        'device_type':'cisco_ios',
        'ip':'192.168.50.145',
        'username':'me',
        'password':'12345',
        'secret':'12345',
        'port':'22'
        }
        cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
        netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
        #print("connection established with", devices['ip'])

        output = netconnect.send_command(cmd)
        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 
                'output':output})
    else:
        form = CmdForm()
    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CmdForm(forms.Form):
        command = forms.CharField(label='Command to execute')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('Automation_page/', views.form_name_view,name='IP form'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index,name='first'),
    path('first_app/',include('first_app.urls')),
    ]
```

forms.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>FORMS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1> IP address form </h1>
   <p>Run command:</p>
   <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
   <input type="submit" value="Run command!" />
   </form><br>
   {% if request.POST %}
    <p>Command output:</p>
    <pre>{{ output }}</pre>
    {% endif %}
   </body>
  </html>
```

i am getting the error when i visit the Automation_page/

> ValueError at /Automation_page/
>   The view first_app.views.form_name_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Automation_page/
>   Django Version: 2.2.3
>   Exception Type: ValueError
>   Exception Value:
>   The view first_app.views.form_name_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
>   Exception Location: K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 126
>   Python Executable:  K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['K:\Work\DevNet\first_project',
>    'K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\Scripts\python37.zip',
>    'K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\DLLs',
>    'K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\lib',
>    'K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\Scripts',
>    'c:\users\karti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib',
>    'c:\users\karti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs',
>    'K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1',
>    'K:\Work\DevNet\ENV1\lib\site-packages']

Need help on this.
thanku who are willing to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution of my problem.
sharing it for others if they can relate. :-)

In views.py
Add the following code, with indent to first if statement.

```
else:
    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line needs to be moved one indent to the left, so it is hit if the form is invalid.

```
else:
    form = CmdForm()
return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
```